# How do I partition an observable of an array of values in one step still utilizing async pipe?

Tags: arrays, angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I receive an observable containing an array of objects. I want to partition the array into two based on a property of each object. I'd like to do this in such a way that the resulting arrays are in observables that can use the `async` pipe in the template, rather than having to manually manage subscriptions. I'm using RxJS 6 with Angular 9.

The trouble I'm having is in trying to partition based on individual elements while returning arrays to the destructuring assignment. I have tried variations of

```
public groupA: Observable<IItem[]>;
public groupB: Observable<IItem[]>;

...

// assigned values are not arrays
[this.groupA, this.groupB] = partition(
    this.service.item$.pipe(
        // split array into stream of its elements
        concatAll(),
    ),
    (item: IItem) => belongsInGroupA(item.myGroup)
);
```

and

```
[this.groupA, this.groupB] = partition(
    this.service.item$,
    (items: IItem[]) => {
        return ???;
        // How do I partition each item without first splitting into individual elements?
    }
);
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-wyxgcx?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts)

I know I could build the two arrays using something like `map` (or, more appropriately, `tap`), but I don't know how to auto-(un)subscribe using `async` with that, if it's even possible.

`partition` seems intended to divide streams of one item at a time, but my need feels like something well within the domain of Angular+RxJS and I just lack the understanding. Can you help?

Comment: what is the data here and what is expected output?

Comment: Input and output are all observables of arrays of the same type of object. Output is the input split on one of the input objects' properties. Check the StackBlitz demo.

Comment: can you give data sample?

Comment: When the component is destroyed the async pipe is automatically unsubscribed, so I believe you could use the tap strategy safely, should you choose to.

Comment: My approach to `tap` is that I loop through the source array once and build the two output arrays as I go. I can't stream each individual element to `*ngFor`, and waiting until the arrays are built to use `of()` or `from()` seems foolish. In other words, I don't know how `async` applies. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
private version1() {
    [this.groupCabbages, this.groupKings] = partition(
      new Observable((observer) => {
        source.subscribe((res: IItem[]) => {
          for(let i = 0; i< res.length; i++) {
            observer.next(res[i]);
          }
          observer.complete();
        })
      }),
      (item: IItem) => {
        return item.myGroup === 'cabbages';
      }
    );
    this.groupCabbages = this.groupCabbages.pipe(toArray());
    this.groupKings = this.groupKings.pipe(toArray());
    // elements are correctly sorted, but streamed one at a time
    this.groupCabbages.subscribe(res => {
      console.log('v1 cabbages', res);
    });
    this.groupKings.subscribe(res => {
      console.log('v1 kings', res);
    });
  }
```

Working Stackblitz :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-cazbuc?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts

Comment: This is identical to `version2` in the demo I shared. It doesn't work because the predicate receives `IItem[]` instead of `IItem`.

Comment: can you give me what you receive from service.item$?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-wyxgcx?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts

Comment: updated the answer, groupCabbages  and groupkings now hold two observable, you can use async pipe with them in template, or can subscribe to them like the sample given above.

Comment: This seems equivalent to my `versionX`, except you're doing in `map`+callback what I do in `tap`. How does this work without `subscribe` (using `async`)?

Comment: check the updated answer please, and yes this would work with async pipe as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your array elements to observable emits by `mergeMap`, then `groupBy` the property, and emit an arrays for each group.

Something like this perhaps:

```
private versionZ() {
   source
     .pipe(
       mergeMap((items: IItem[]) => from(items)),
       groupBy((item: IItem) => item.myGroup),
       mergeMap((group: Observable<any>) => group.pipe(toArray()))
     )
     .subscribe(t => console.log(t));
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just have to apply `toArray()` operator

```
 this.groupCabbagesForView = this.groupCabbages.pipe(toArray())
 // in view 
 groupCabbagesForView | async
```

then it is consumable by the view async pipe. View will get the list of items instead of item by item.

Comment: This requires me to manage the subscription that generates `this.groupCabbages`.

Comment: async pipe will be the only place that subscription happens, you don't need to manage any subscription if your code is right.

Answer (score 0):

RxJS `partition` is used to split *observable* streams. You on the other hand need to create two different streams based on a condition applied to elements of *each notification* of the stream. If the number of elements in each emission is fairly limited and if you need to create only a limited number of observables, I'd say it'd be quicker to create multiple observables individually using the `map` operator.

**Controller**

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.cabbages$ = this.source$.pipe(
    map((items: IItem[]) =>
      items.filter((item: IItem) => item.myGroup === 'cabbages')
    )
  );

  this.kings$ = this.source$.pipe(
    map((items: IItem[]) =>
      items.filter((item: IItem) => item.myGroup === 'kings')
    )
  );
}
```

**Template**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(cabbages$ | async) as cabbages">
  Cabbages:
  <div *ngFor="let cabbage of cabbages">
    {{ cabbage | json }}
  </div>
</ng-container>
<br>

<ng-container *ngIf="(kings$ | async) as kings">
  Kings:
  <div *ngFor="let king of kings">
    {{ king | json }}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3adiqz?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Note: Each `async` pipe would trigger a separate subscription to the `source$` observable stream. If too many `async` pipes are needed it might lead to performance issues.

Comment: This is very close to my initial approach. I'm trying to avoid iterating through the list more than once, which led to this SO question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, then the essence is that you want to obtain 2 observables with values derived from a single observable.  The general way to do this would be to multicast the original, then use that to create the derived observables.

```
temp$ = obs1$.pipe(share());
obs2$ = temp$.pipe(map(value => ...));
obs3$ = temp$.pipe(map(value => ...));
```

So to apply this to your example:

```
temp$ = this.service.item$.pipe(
   map(arr => splitArr(arr, belongsInGroupA));
   // splitArr returns [arrA, arrB]
);


this.groupA = temp$.pipe(map(value => value[0]));
this.groupB = temp$.pipe(map(value => value[1]));
```

The remaining question is how to [efficiently split the array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162878/partitioning-an-array-based-on-a-condition-in-javascript), but this is normal array manipulation.  If a single-pass is important then use reduce.